# Why doesn't the Ruger set off the metal detector?

Tags: the-dark-tower, song-of-susannah

In *The Dark Tower VI: Song of Susannah* towards the end of the book Jake and Pere Callahan go under the WTC to put Black 13 in a long-term storage locker. It is mentioned that the Orizas Jake is carrying do not set off the metal detector they have to pass through. However, it doesn't mention that the Ruger Callahan is packing (lent to him by Jake) doesn't set it off as well.

How could a Ruger make it through the metal detector? It seemed odd to me that they specifically mention the Orizas which brought up in my mind their companion weapon, the Ruger.

Comment: Excellent question. I went back and read the relevant chapters and while the Ruger is not specifically mentioned when they go through the metal detector, it is mentioned a short while later when Jake pulls it out of his pockets when they arrive at the Dixie Pig.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is that Stephen King messed up. Robin Furth mentions a few of his continuity slips in her concordance, and he owns up to them himself. For instance, Ruger has never manufactured a .44 automatic with a "clip" as it is described.

We COULD chalk this up to alternaverse physics, similar to Eddie Dead living in Co-Op City in Brooklyn (it's actually in the Bronx), but it's far more likely that King simply made a small human error that didn't really affect the quality of the (incredibly good) book series. For a list of other firearm based errors in the series, check this list - I have submitted this error to it for review.

http://stephenkingbloopers.wikia.com/wiki/Firearm_errors

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruger_MK_II), SR&Co. apparently made variants of the MK II Ruger .22 and .45 with polymer frames, rather than steel. It's possible that these polymer weapons would have had too little metal to be detected by a standard metal detector.

Comment: The same wikipedia article mentions that the MK II with polymer frame was introduced in 1982. Jake steals the Ruger from his father in 1977.

Comment: Gah! Foiled again! ;-)

Comment: Of course, since Jake didn't come from the Keystone World, I suppose it's possible that it was produced earlier in his world. Seems like a bit of a contrivance though.

Comment: Even if the timeline worked out, firearms with polymer frames still have a substantial amount of metal in the barrel and slide. Other examples of common polymer framed handguns are Glocks and the Springfield XD(m) series.